# Why on scrolling my progress bar move on window scroll not on my div reactjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

Here, is my code. 
My progress bar work fine. It show movable progress bar on window scroll. but i want it move when i scroll my div.
Here i am using js query.

Also Is it okay to write jquery function in componentWillmount.

```js
export default class NewPreview extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        self = this;
        this.scrollPercent=''
        this.xmlType=''
        this.d=''
        this.c=''
        this.state = {
        }
    }

  
    componentWillMount() {
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log("h")
            var s = $(window).scrollTop()
                  this.d = $(document).height()
                  this.c = $(window).height()
                this.scrollPercent = (s / (d-c)) * 100;
                  var position = scrollPercent;
          
             $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);
          
          });
        
    }


    render() {
        const panel_body = {
            borderLeft: "3px solid #00BCD4",
            height: "90px",
            backgroundColor:"lightyellow",
            borderRadius:"4px",
            margin:"6px"
        }
        const progress ={
            width:"40%",
              position:"fixed",
              top:"103px",
              backgroundColor:"red"
          }
        const panel_XML = {
            color: "#00BCD4",
            fontSize: "17px",
            position: "relative",
            left: "12px",
            top: "10px"
        }
        if(this.xmlType='slideshow'){
            return (
                <div id="progressBarID">
                    <progress style={progress} id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                    {this.state.newXML.map((data,item)=>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" style={panel_body}>
                            <p style={panel_XML}>{data.header}</p>
                            <p style={panel_XML}>{data.article}</p>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            )
        }
        else if(this.xmlType='timeline') {
            return(
                <div>heloo</div>
            )
        }
    }

}
```

What should i do to move my progress bar on my div scrolling not on my window scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, but you should put the percent into the state so the component will re-render (also changed to `componentDidMount`):

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollHandler);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  // remove scroll listener
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollHandler);
}

// it's good to extract the scroll handler into a function
onScrollHandler = () => {
  const s = $(window).scrollTop();
  const d = $(document).height();
  const c = $(window).height();
  const scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
  this.setState({
    scrollPercent
  });
}
```

and then change the css width based on the state:

```
const progress = {
  width: `${this.state.scrollPercent}%`,
  ...
```

It's ok to use jquery if you need it elsewhere in your app, but if you just want to add a scroll listener you can get rid of it. **I updated the code to remove jquery since it's not really needed here.**

---

**See demo:**

```js
class NewPreview extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.scrollPercent = 0;
        this.xmlType='slideshow'
        this.d=''
        this.c=''
        this.state = {
          newXML: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollHandler);
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
      // remove scroll listener
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollHandler);
    }
    
    onScrollHandler = () => {
      const s = $(window).scrollTop();
      const d = $(document).height();
      const c = $(window).height();
      const scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
      this.setState({
        scrollPercent
      });
    }

    render() {
        const panel_body = {
            borderLeft: "3px solid #00BCD4",
            height: "90px",
            backgroundColor:"lightyellow",
            borderRadius:"4px",
            margin:"6px"
        }
        const progress = {
            width: `${this.state.scrollPercent}%`,
              position:"fixed",
              top:"103px",
              backgroundColor:"red",
              height: '20px'
          }
        const panel_XML = {
            color: "#00BCD4",
            fontSize: "17px",
            position: "relative",
            left: "12px",
            top: "10px"
        }
        if(this.xmlType='slideshow'){
            return (
                <div id="progressBarID">
                    Scroll down
                    <div style={progress} id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></div>
                    {this.state.newXML.map((data,item)=>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" style={panel_body}>
                            <p style={panel_XML}>{data.header}</p>
                            <p style={panel_XML}>{data.article}</p>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            )
        }
        else if(this.xmlType='timeline') {
            return(
                <div>heloo</div>
            )
        }
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NewPreview />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
#app {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 800px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Comment: yeh!!... thank you. can you tell me how i do same thing but this this time my div show in slider like corousel.

Comment: @HELP Please create another question and mark this answer as resolved. This is not your personal support employee.

Comment: who are you @apercu